# How can my program stop running when a user's number goal is met?

Tags: python, while-loop

The purpose of my program is for the user to type in a donation goal. When that number goal is met, my program is supposed to stop. After asking the user for a goal, then my program asks for a donation amount and each donation amount adds on to each other leading up to the goal. Finally, after inputting multiple donation amounts, it should add up to the goal.

```
goal = ''
userDonation = ''
totalAmount = 0
userCashList = []

#asking for end goal
goal = int(input("Some Charity Donation Tracker... Please enter your goal: "))
print("Current Amount: ", totalAmount)

while totalAmount != goal:
  userDonation = int(input("Please Enter Donation Amount: "))
  print("Current Amount: ", userDonation + totalAmount)
  userCashList.append(totalAmount)
  for cash in userCashList:
      totalAmount += userDonation
  if userDonation == goal:
      print("You have met your goal!")
  else:
      userCashList.append(userDonation)
```

Output:

```
Some Charity Donation Tracker... Please enter your goal: 100
Current Amount:  0
Please Enter Donation Amount: 200
Current Amount:  200
Please Enter Donation Amount: 300
Current Amount:  500
Please Enter Donation Amount: 200
Current Amount:  1300
Please Enter Donation Amount:
```

My donation amounts are adding, but why can't it stop at 100?

Comment: Perhaps `totalAmount < goal` instead of `!=`? Also you might want to change the condition for `print("You have met your goal!")`.

Comment: Note that instead of only stopping if the goal is met exactly, you are also making some weird computations in there that make little sense.  You keep adding `userDonation` for the number of donations made every iteration.

Comment: my program now can meet my users goal! But how should I change my condition? @j1-lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the `userCashList` array when you already have `totalAmount` to display the donations so far. Anyway, I have made several changes to your code and it seems to work fine!

Firstly, `while totalAmount != goal` will only run if `totalAmount` is not exactly what `goal` is. This means that if you hit the goal right on the mark, ie. a user donates 100 with a goal of 100, the code will just pass the while loop without indicating that you have passed the goal.

Here is the new code:

```
goal = ''
userDonation = ''
totalAmount = 0

#asking for end goal
goal = int(input("Some Charity Donation Tracker... Please enter your goal: "))
print("Current Amount: ", totalAmount)

while True:
  userDonation = int(input("Please Enter Donation Amount: "))
  totalAmount = totalAmount + userDonation
  print("Current Amount: ", totalAmount)
  if totalAmount >= goal:
      print("You have met your goal!")
      break # Break out of the loop when the goal is met
```

Instead of just running when the total is not equal to the goal, the `while` loop runs forever. This is stopped by the `if` statement which checks every increment if the total is equal to or greater than the goal. If so, inform the user and break out of the loop, thus stopping the script.

I am new to answering SO questions, so I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

> **when your condition `!=` this means the loop will stop only if `total_amount` is equal the goal (your program enter infinite loop if
> `total_amount` greater than goal), instead of just use `<` (less than
> operator).**

**your code but improved:**

```
total_amount = 0

# asking for end goal
goal = int(input("Some Charity Donation Tracker... Please enter your goal: "))
print("Current Amount:", total_amount)

while total_amount < goal:
    user_donation = int(input("Please Enter Donation Amount:"))
    total_amount += user_donation
    print("Current Amount: ", total_amount)
else:
    print("You have met your goal!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify your code with lesser variables. Do check if this is a better solution to your problem or not.

```
userDonation = ''
userCashList = []

#asking for end goal
goal = int(input("Some Charity Donation Tracker... Please enter your goal: "))
print("Current Amount: ", sum(userCashList))

while sum(userCashList) <= goal:
  userDonation = int(input("Please Enter Donation Amount: "))
  userCashList.append(userDonation)
  print("Current Amount: ", sum(userCashList))
  if sum(userCashList) >= goal:
      print("You have met your goal!")
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems here:

### Wrong stop condition in the while

Your current condition is `totalAmount != goal`, but the problem is that to stop, your `totalAmount` have to be exactly the same of the established goal, and if the goal is exceeded and by the `totalAmount` but never get to be equal to it then the loop will never stop.This is why your stop condition in the while loop should be `totalAmount < goal`.

### Wrong increment of the totalAmount

Your totalAmount is been over incresed in this for loop:

```
for cash in userCashList:
      totalAmount += userDonation
```

This for loop is totally inncesessary and is affecting the correct functionallity of your app.

This is how I recommend your code should be:

```
goal = ''
userDonation = ''
totalAmount = 0
userCashList = []

#asking for end goal
goal = int(input("Some Charity Donation Tracker... Please enter your goal: "))
print("Current Amount: ", totalAmount)

while totalAmount < goal:
    userDonation = int(input("Please Enter Donation Amount: "))
    print("Current Amount: ", userDonation + totalAmount)
    userCashList.append(userDonation)
    totalAmount += userDonation
    if totalAmount >= goal:
        print("You have met your goal!")
```

As you can see here there is no need for use a break, with the loop condition is enougth. Also I asume that userCashList was some kind of record for the donations.